# How do I create a rectangle to be as a sprite in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

I was just trying to make a rectangle in pygame as a variable, but it showed an error. I really don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?
The code:

```
import pygame as py

screen = py.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
rocket = py.draw.rect((screen), (225, 225, 225), (600, 350))
py.display.flip()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\Project files\shooter_game.py", line 24, in <module>
    rocket = py.draw.rect((screen), (225, 225, 225), (600, 350))
TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1200, 700])
screen.fill([0, 0, 0])
pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0, 0], [50, 50, 90, 90], 0)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter of [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) has to be a tuple with a size of 4. The tuple specifies a rectangle with the position and size:

<s>`py.draw.rect((screen), (225, 225, 225), (0, 0, 600, 350))`</s>

```py
py.draw.rect((screen), (225, 225, 225), (600, 350, 20, 20))
```

`pygame.draw.rect()` does not generate a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. The operation draw a rectangle to a surface and returns a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object.
If you want to generate a rectangular object which can be `blit` to a surface, then you have to generate a `pygame.Surface` and [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) it with a uniform color:

```py
rocket = py.Surface((20, 20))
rocket.fill((225, 225, 225))
```

```py
screen.blit(rocket, (600, 350))
```